# building java SOAP client to access comscore api

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client

I am looking for a simple java client which allows me to access simple SOAP api's. they expose their SOAP webservice as a HTTPS service with ‘Basic Auth’ protocol for authentication.

Can someone tell me how can I test my changes.

Answer (score 0):

If **they** provide WSDL files for their SOAP interfaces, you can generate Java stub classes out of that. SOAP implementations like [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) and [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) provide a `wsdl2java` tool that helps you with this. Then you can use the stub classes to talk to the remote SOAP services. Axis and CXF documentation has more information.